# bash - read input into variable/password in bash

Tags: bash

Is it possible to store something - for example user input - into a variable in bash? I have a script that reads a password...

```
#!/bin/bash

while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do
    key="$1";
    case $key in
        -p|--prompt)
            if [ ! "$2" ]; then
                printf "\e31;1mMust pass in a prompt\e[0m\n";
                exit 1;
            fi
            printf "$2";
            shift 2;
            ;;
    esac
done

psswd=;
c=;
while [ "$c" != "^M" ]; do
    read -n 1 -s c;
    if [ "$c" == "^?" ]; then
        if [ ${#psswd} -gt 0 ]; then
            psswd=${psswd:: -1};
            printf "\b \b";
        fi
    elif [ ! "$c" ]; then # pressed enter
        break;
    else
        psswd="$psswd$c";
        printf "*";
    fi
done;

printf "\nYour entered password is: $psswd\n"
```

(sorry, `^M` is newline and `^?` is backspace. Meaning you can't copy and paste, but that is how it shows up in vim, and I don't know how else to write it.)

... and I would like the password to be strored into a variable. You know how `read` stores a variable. If `read` can do it, why can't I? Does anyone have any ideas?

(Or perhaps there is a better way to store the password... like `echo "$psswd" | base64 > .pass` - which isn't really what I want to do.)

---

### UPDATE

Basically, how do I get my `psswd` into a variable outside the shell? **OR** how do I access the password once that shell is closed? Is there a better way to store it other than a variable?

Comment: pf thanks. A programming question gets down-voted for being off topic. Would anyone care to explain why this is off-topic? (Someone is cranky at 06:20.)

Comment: The `-n 1` parameter to `read` means that only a single character will be read.  Is that what you want?  Otherwise, `read -s c` should indeed store your input into $c

Comment: @rojomoke yes, I want to read in *one* character at a time so that I can print an asterisk.

Comment: Storing passwords in env is insecure. Anyone with privilege to traverse the /proc filesystem will be able to get your cleartext password. I will suggest kerberizing your environment. Although kerberos ticket can be stolen (copied) by privileged users, they will not be able to know your cleartext password. If you still want to proceed with it, all you need to do is export the variable. This will only work outside the script if the script is sourced. If the script is executed, then the exported variable is lost upon termination of the script.

Answer (score 3):

As rojomoke suggests, this is enough:

```
read -p "Enter your password: " -s pw
echo "You entered: $pw"
```

If you do this: `read -n 1 -s c` and you just hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>, then `$c` will be empty, it will not hold `\r`; and if you hit backspace, in my testing, $c holds a character with octal value 177

```
read -n 1 -s c
printf "%s" "$c" | od -c
```

Documentation: [*Bash Reference Manual. Bash Builtins: `read`*](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Builtins.html#index-read)

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear. My question is once I have the password in the `psswd` variable, how do I store that into a variable that can then be accessed outside the shell it is running in. I know about `read -s`, but I wanted to implement my own so that I could print the `*`s.

Comment: (or perhaps there is a better way to store a password than a variable?)